# How to check if an EC2 instance is SSH ready or not via bash script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I've written a script which starts an EC2 instance and then runs the application. Post successful job run event, it will shutdown the EC2 instance.

This job runs on scheduled time on Jenkins, configured via ansible.

Recently I have been noticing that my EC2 instance starts but fails to perform ssh on the machine due to which my cron job does not gets triggered / started. With EC2 running instance, it may or may not be ready for the ssh.

I'm using this way to check my EC2 instance running status:

```sh
while [ "$ec2_instance_status" != '"running"' ]; do
    echo "=======instance state - $ec2_instance_status======="
    sleep 10
    ec2_instance_status=$(aws --region=ap-southeast-2 --profile=prod ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids $instance_id | jq ".InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceState.Name")
done
```

I am looking to add a step in this part, where it can check if EC2 instance is ready for the ssh. If it's not ready, it will again wait before running next tasks.

How this can be done? I've been looking over the internet for a solution but didn't found anything relevant close to solving this issue. This will help me to make my cron job failure proof at trigger step.

Comment: The normal way to do this is to pass your script as `user-data` to the EC2 instance so it will run on startup. That way you don't have to `ssh` into the instance at all.

Comment: @MarkB I didn't get it. Can you share any reference?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Answer (score 0):

A User Data script can automatically run code when an instance is *first* started.

If you want to run a script *every time* that an instance is started, place the script in:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

For an example, see: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)